# Regular expression to match a number with 2 digits at most and optionally 2 decimals at most

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I've been searching for the past few days but the only kinds of regex that I find are like this:

```
(\d{0,2})\.?\d{1,2}$
```

This works well with inputs like:

```
9
99
9.9
9.99
99.9
99.99
.9
.99
```

Everything's OK with those, but it also happens to accept inputs like

```
999
9999
```

I don't want this to happen. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: That's because you're *optionally* accepting the period character

Comment: you should not "search for regexp", but construct it according to your requirments

Comment: You make the email regex then, @Lashane :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with alternation:

```
^(?:\d{1,2}|\d{0,2}\.\d{1,2})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/2)

**RegEx Description:**

```
^           # start
(?:         # start non-capturing group
   \d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits
   |        # OR
   \d{0,2}  # match 0 to 2 digits
   \.       # followed by DOT
   \d{1,2}  # match 1 or 2 digits
)           # end non-capturing group
$           # end
```

Comment: Heh, I was going for a negative lookbehind, but that's good too. +1

Comment: @Farkie: There is no lookbehind in Javascript

Comment: He never actually said what he's using it in (also mentioned PHP, which would work :))

Answer (score 0):

Use following regex

```
(\d{0,2})\.\.?\d{0,2}$
```

Comment: Doesn't match 9 or 99

Comment: Yes, I already found it, sorry. Will try to find correct regex.